# Sources on P1/N1 modulation with checkerboard probe

Tags: vision, eeg, attention, electrophysiology, event-related-potential

I have been able to find a lot of papers that modulate the P1/N1 component with a visual probe, usually a checkerboard presented parafoveally. I understand the basics of what I am reading, but I would like to find more information about the basic effect of P1/N1 modulation with this type of stimuli. All papers I find present some new variation on the experimental paradigm, whereas I would like to read about the original effects, so I can use it on an experiment I am currently designing.

Does anyone know of a good review, book chapters, article, etc. describing this experimental paradigm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the fundamentals, I always go back to the more dated literature that is heavily cited (in this field of research, which is pretty big given it uses visual evoked potentials, say >1k times). I found the following two papers that describe the basics of VEPs with checkerboard patterns.

In addition, a very nice visual electrophysiology book is *Electrophysiologic Testing*, by Fishman *et al* (eds.). That book has greatly helped me to understand the basics of these matters. For you, especially section 5.1 to 5.3 seem relevant as they deal with the basics and stimulus parameters of VEPs, including checkerboard patterns. Section 5.6 delivers practical guidelines that may also be of great use to you.

[- Fisman *et al*. (eds.), ch. 5. Electrophysiologic testing in disorders of the Retina, optic nerve, and visual pathway, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. FAAO, San Fransisco, CA](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Electrophysiologic-Testing-in-Disorders-of-the-and-Duncan/171bf31ea966cf506713883129fc51b1af8ab2d7)

[- Lehman & Skrendies. Reference-free identification of components of checkerboard-evoked multichannel potential fields. *Electroencephal Clin Neurophysiol* (1980);  **48**: 609-21](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0013469480904198?token=20EF5C00AC7CF39E1812B805FC5239DA7F0F57D0C6E13B2CA2C1BB591BB5D012F34AF5E6A66520CF323345E1431D23C3&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210628083016)

[- Shigeto *et al*., Visual evoked cortical magnetic responses to checkerboard pattern reversal stimulation: A study on the neural generators of N75, P100 and N145. *J Neurol Sci* (1998); **156**(2): 186-94](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022510X98000264?token=26DAC77269469F98D01894455058A4C2B027E6629B1355E2F4C9EECD41FD1019DFCD2425CF4A06A73BFD14D478514317&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210628083658)